# if statement in python not executing

Tags: python-3.x

```
from random import randint
proceed = "Y"
while(proceed == 'Y' or proceed == 'y'):
    print("Guess the Integer or 'exit'")
    number = input()
    x1 = randint(0, 9)
    if number is x1 :
        print("You guessed it right")
    else:
        print("number was ", x1)
    print("Do you want to continue, Y or N?")
    proceed = input()
```

In the above code, `if` statement is not executing. Is it because of `==` operator not being used?

Answer (score 0):

By using:

```
if number is x1:
```

you are testing if the variable `number` is the variable `x1` (i.e. do their values occupy the same spot in the computers memory), and **not** if there values are the same.

Use:

```
if number == str(x1):
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns a string and therefore the check:

```
if number is x1 :
```

will always fail because a string will never be the same instance as integer.

Instead convert to an integer and check for equality:

```
number = int(input())
x1 = randint(0, 9)
if number == x1:
    print("You guessed it right")
```